# an array of permutation arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

Suppose I have an array of 15 numbers, namely [0,1,2...14], how do I generate an array (or arraylist) which contains any 100 permutations of the given array? (The target array will have 100 elements, where each element is a permutation of the given array. )

Comment: Make a copy of your array, permute it, repeat 100 times.  Since you haven't shown any work that you've done so far, nor given any indication of what, specifically, it is that you're having trouble with, it's difficult to be more specific, short of just writing your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Read my article [on Permutations with Java 8](http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.com/2015/07/java-8-master-permutations.html)! and you will be able to complete your task!